# How to move the default expandable list group indicator from left to right?

Tags: android, android-layout, expandablelistview

`Except for creating your own layout`, is there any way to move the group indicator from left side to right side?

I am wondering dose Android has such attribute to handle this?

Also, what exactly `android:indicatorStart|End|Left|Right` does? I looked at the documentation still have no idea about it.

Answer (score 1):

First there are 2 ways of moving group icon indicator depending on devices android version, thus for devices with sdk version 18 and up (android 4.3 and higher) there is a method called `setIndicatorBoundsRelative(left,right)`, as for the lower versions there is another method called `setIndicatorBounds(left,right)`. Both of the above functions change the bounds of the group indicator where the first parameter will set the a position of the indicator to start from and right will set the position of the indicator to end.

The code:
In the activity where expandablelist is declared and initialized, declare the following as class variables(apart from adapter and view of expandableListView)

```
DisplayMetrics diaplayMetrics;
int width;
```

In the on create function:

```
@Override
onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //initialze displayMetrics
    metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    //get the metrics of window
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
    save width of window
    width = metrics.widthPixels;
    //check version of sdk(android version)
    if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2) {
               //For sdk version bellow 18
           expandableListView.setIndicatorBounds(width - GetDipsFromPixel(50), width - GetDipsFromPixel(10));
    } else {
               //For sdk 18 and above 
           expandableListView.setIndicatorBoundsRelative(width - GetDipsFromPixel(50), width - GetDipsFromPixel(10));
    }
    expandableListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
}

private int GetDipsFromPixel(int pixels) {
     // Get the screen's density scale
     final float scale = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
     // Convert the dps to pixels, based on density scale
     return (int) (pixels * scale + 0.5f);
}
```